# Wallet adapter throwing error in one of the dependencies

Tags: solana-program, web3.js, solana-wallet-adapter

I have created a react app, when I try `npm run`, I am getting this error:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/@toruslabs/eccrypto/browser.js 9:17-34

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto'
```

Dependencies in package.json looks like this:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@project-serum/anchor": "^0.24.2",
    "@solana-mobile/wallet-adapter-mobile": "^0.9.0",
    "@solana/wallet-adapter-base": "^0.9.13",
    "@solana/wallet-adapter-react": "^0.15.15",
    "@solana/wallet-adapter-react-ui": "^0.9.13",
    "@solana/wallet-adapter-wallets": "^0.18.2",
    "@solana/web3.js": "^1.53.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.1.1",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.0.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "stream": "^0.0.2",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
```

Node.js v17.3.0

Any idea how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the following to your package.json

```
  "browser": {
    "crypto": false
  },
```

If it doesn't work (when node version is 17), also add the following to your package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "crypto-browserify": "^3.12.0",
    "crypto": "npm:crypto-browserify",
    "stream": "npm:stream-browserify"
  },
```